# How would you use HyperDev to access third-party APIs when all your server-side code is public and there's no place to store your private keys?

Tags: node.js, cloud

https://hyperdev.com is a way to write server-side code quickly and easily.  It's not meant for production, but quick prototypes, training, or just sample code you want to share on stackoverflow.   But sometimes you might want to show an example that requires a third-party API, such as Twitter, or Google or w/e.   In a real server-side web application, that information would not be kept in source, but perhaps an environment variable, or something like that.

But with https://hyperdev.com, everything is public.   Other than having a edit-box that you require the user enter *their* key in, is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://hyperdev.com/help/faqs/
.env is a secure environment config section in your projects, useful for storing API keys and app credentials. Only invited collaborators are able to see the contents of your .env file. So anonymous viewers or logged-in users who haven’t been invited to your project can’t see them. When remixing an app the values are cleared so they’re not copied across.